# what folder does admin live in?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, htaccess

I'm troubleshooting an admin issue for a 3rd party's Magento CE 1.9.?. They "renamed" their admin URL, but they also secured their admin using `.htaccess` to restrict access to specific IP.

I'm trying to find the `.htaccess` file that does this in FTP, but can't find an `/admin` or `/new-admin-URL` directory.

- What folder does the admin live in?
- What `.htaccess` would contain the restricted IPs? I can't see those restrictions in the web root's `.htaccess`.

Comment: Which magento version you are using ?

Comment: Which version of magento you are working on. If it is Magento 1.9.x then you will find your admin URL from app/etc/local.xml and if it is magento 2.x then you will find your admin URL from app/etc/env.php

Comment: Thx @Nits. It's CE 1.9. In `app/etc/local.xml` I see "new-admin-URL" but can't find this folder in FTP.

Comment: there won't be any folder "admin-url" as magento does not follow such structure, if you are checking for .htaccess, you will find one at root and another in app directory

Comment: Thx @Piyush. I can now see the `/app/.htaccess` but this does not contain the IP restriction. /confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Steve, 
Admin path will either be set in `app/etc/local.xml` file or overwritten by Magento admin and can be verified in `core_config_data` table where `path=admin/url/custom`.

Developer IP restriction can be done by admin panel as well. If you are not finding this in .htaccess then check this as well ...

**System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer**

[image]

If you have the database access, then you can modify this record in `core_config_data` table where `path=dev/restrict/allow_ips`
this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can find admin path from

```
app/etc/env.php
```

under

```
  'frontName' => 'youradminpath',
```

Comment: That is for Magento 2.X not all magento 1.9